# I need to change the link for a specific button above 768px width with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, syntax, frontend

I have an issue with a facebook button on my wordpress site, in mobile it was opening browsers instead of opening the fb app, so I changed the link to a fb:// but now on desktop it throws a message before heading to the facebook page to "open AddressUrlForwarder" before letting you in. I want to keep the button as is for 768px resolutions and below because thats my breakpoint, and above just have the regular facebook www. url. At first I thought a media query could solve it but I realized there must be a much simpler way with jQuery, a replacewith with and if maybe, Im just not very keen on the syntax. Thanks for the help

All I've done is change with jQuery the default [www.facebook.com/..](http://www.facebook.com/..). to the fb://..., the button is set automatically when the url is written in the theme, so I had to change the link type with jQuery. As of that moment I was expecting it not to be a problem on desktop, but when I tried it, it showed the "open AddressUrlForwarder" message.

Comment: Viewport dimension is most definitely not a suitable means to detect "mobile".  This is something that you should likely implement at the CDN edge of your application via a worker (if you are using cloudflare) or an equivalent technology.  Varying the response based on UA is pretty trivial if the proper tools are used.

Comment: Not really @Yogi, it seems this answer had several issues way back

Comment: @LukeA.Leber I understand my solution is not great, I just assumed maybe JS could be switched out like CSS can be with a media query... it is a simple button, right now its set so that in mobile it takes you to the FB app, even if you're not logged in, but in desktop browsers i get this prompt about the addresurlforwader because the custom JS has that link as a fb:// instead of a normal link, it seems like someone must of faced this before, sorry for the long answer, but I'm not even sure I understand your suggestion, not sure how to aprorach it.